# How do I change the dot colour in geom_dotplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, colors

I'm trying to change the fill colour of dots in a combined bar graph/dot plot graphic. I have the following code:

```
df <- read.csv("df.csv")
df$label <- factor(df$label, levels = c("label 1","label 2"))
df$a <- factor(df$a, levels = c("10000","NTC"))
df$b <- factor(df$b, levels = c("0","2","5","10"))
df$y <- as.numeric(df$y)
df_SE <- summarySE(df, measurevar="y", groupvars=c("label", "a", "b"), na.rm = TRUE)

p <- ggplot(df_SE, aes(x=interaction(a, b), y = y, fill=label))+
geom_bar(stat="identity", size=0.75, position=position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.7,
           color="black")+
  geom_errorbar(data=df_SE , aes(ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se),
                position=position_dodge(0.8), size=0.5, width=.1, colour="black")+
  geom_dotplot(data = df, aes(x=interaction(df$a, df$b), y = df$y),
               binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = .35, 
               position =position_dodge(0.8))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#A6CEE3", "#1F78B4"),name= "label",labels=c("label 1","label 2"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,30), breaks = seq(0,30,5))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.title = element_text(family = "Helvetica", face = "bold", size = (15)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Helvetica",colour = "black",
                                   size = rel(1.5)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Helvetica",colour = "black",
                                   size = rel(1.5)),
        axis.title = element_text(colour="black",family = "Helvetica",
                                  size = rel(1.5)),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black",
                                   family = "Helvetica", size = rel(1.5)),
        legend.title = element_text(colour = "black",size = rel(2),
                                    family = "Helvetica"),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black",
                                 size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"))+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=13, face = 'bold'),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="white"),
        axis.text.x =element_text(size=12, vjust = 0.2),
        legend.text.align = 0)+
  labs(x="x", y="y")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 30, color = "red")
print(p)
```

Which gives me the following graphic.
[Graphic output from provided code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEtaK.png)

However, notice the dots are the same colour as the bars, which makes them difficult to see. I want them to be simply black. I've tried specifying with the code:

```
geom_dotplot(data = df, aes(x=interaction(df$a, df$b, fill = "black"), y = df$y),
           binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = .35, 
           position =position_dodge(0.8))
```

but it offsets the dots from the bars in the graphic that I either can't or don't know how to fix. Adding the `fill` command outside of `aes()` like below:

```
geom_dotplot(data = df, aes(x=interaction(df$a, df$b) , fill = "black", y = df$y),
           binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = .35, 
           position =position_dodge(0.8))
```

gives me a message saying

> "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2
> provided."

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Regards,

Comment: Well, all this code is not useful if you don't add data. Add data using `dput(df_SE)`. Read how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Without data, I could not test it. You could try to add `color = "black"` and move `fill = "black"` outside `aes`:

```
ggplot()
geom_dotplot(data = df, aes(x=interaction(a, b), y = y), 
           fill = "black", color = "black",
           binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = .35, 
           position =position_dodge(0.8))
```

Please let me know if this does not work. I will delete it. Also, I removed all `df$` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

[suggested solution attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8nir.png)
I tried your solution, but doing so removes the identity of the dots. I.e. - they no longer align with their relevant bars in the bar graph.

Here is the data I'm working with;

```
       y     a  b   label
1  11.16 10000  0 label 1
2   8.25   NTC  0 label 1
3  11.11   NTC  2 label 1
4  15.64   NTC  5 label 1
5  30.00   NTC 10 label 1
6   9.87 10000  0 label 1
7   9.07   NTC  0 label 1
8  26.66   NTC  2 label 1
9  22.65   NTC  5 label 1
10 30.00   NTC 10 label 1
11 10.37 10000  0 label 1
12  9.85   NTC  0 label 1
13 12.32   NTC  2 label 1
14 14.87   NTC  5 label 1
15 30.00   NTC 10 label 1
16  6.14 10000  0 label 2
17 20.99   NTC  0 label 2
18 24.53   NTC  2 label 2
19 30.00   NTC  5 label 2
20 30.00   NTC 10 label 2
21  6.20 10000  0 label 2
22 24.93   NTC  0 label 2
23 30.00   NTC  2 label 2
24 30.00   NTC  5 label 2
25 30.00   NTC 10 label 2
26 10.75 10000  0 label 2
27 22.19   NTC  0 label 2
28 30.00   NTC  2 label 2
29 30.00   NTC  5 label 2
30 30.00   NTC 10 label 2
```

Thanks in advance.